# Evaluating asymptote in R nls for multiple factors

Tags: r, nls

I am trying to evaluate if different populations reach different asymptotes using NLS, in R. Here I have two data.frames df1 has only one population (Represented by Site)

```
df1<- structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ALT01", 
"ALT02", "ALT03", "Cotton", "Deep", "Eckhardt", "Green", "Johnson", 
"Kissinger", "Marsh", "Sand", "Shypoke", "Sora", "Spike", "Tamora", 
"WRP01", "WRP05", "WRP08", "WRP10", "WRP11", "WRP12", "WRP14", 
"WRP15", "WRP18"), class = "factor"), Nets = 1:18, Cumulative.spp = c(12L, 
13L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L)), .Names = c("Site", "Nets", "Cumulative.spp"
), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

and df2 has to populations (Again represented by Site)

```
df2 <- structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ALT01", 
"ALT02", "ALT03", "Cotton", "Deep", "Eckhardt", "Green", "Johnson", 
"Kissinger", "Marsh", "Sand", "Shypoke", "Sora", "Spike", "Tamora", 
"WRP01", "WRP05", "WRP08", "WRP10", "WRP11", "WRP12", "WRP14", 
"WRP15", "WRP18"), class = "factor"), Nets = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), Cumulative.spp = c(12L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
7L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L)), .Names = c("Site", "Nets", "Cumulative.spp"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I model for one population everything looks great:

```
Model1<-nls(Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets, A, lrc, c0), data = df1)
```

What I am trying to do is see if I can add several populations to the same model and add a Site Variable, I have tried this:

```
Model2<-nls(Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets, A, lrc, c0) + Site , data = df2)
```

and this:

```
Model2<-nls(Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets + Site , A, lrc, c0), data = df2)
```

But no luck so far, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check out `nlme::gnls()` and in particular the `params` argument ...

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker I was trying to understand the documentation, of `params`, and although it says that _different models for each parameter_ I haven't found any example on how to do that, could you help me a bit more?.

Comment: something approximately like  `gnls(Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets, A, lrc, c0), params = Nets ~ Site, data = df2)` (if you want just the effect of `Nets` to vary across sites) or `params = Nets+A+lrc+c0~Site` if you want all parameters to vary (although in that case you could just subdivide the data and fit each site separately; the only (?) difference would be a pooled vs. site-specific estimate of residual variance)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker as you saw someone came up with a solution using nls but I still want to learn the `gnls` way, I tried both `gnls(Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets, A, lrc, c0), params = Nets ~ Site, data = df2)` and gave me this error: _Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'A' not found_; and `gnls(Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets, A, lrc, c0), params = Nets+A+lrc+c0~Site, data = df2)` gives me another error, this: `gnls(Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets, A, lrc, c0), data = df2)` still works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that you want to have different `Asym` parameters for the two populations but common `lrc` and `c0` parameters.

First in (1) we show how to modify the solution in the question to get the answer.  Most of the code in (1) is just to get starting values but the actual fit is only one line of code -- two lines if you count the fact that we defined the formula in a separate line.

Then in (2) we show how to simplify (1) by using algorithm `"plinear"` eliminating the need to get starting values for the linear parameters.  In (2a) we show a further simplification which extends more readily to more sites and in (2b) we simplify that further under the condition that all sites are present (which is not the case in the question but may be the case in the real data).

**1) default algorithm**  We can get starting values in `nls` by fitting each population separately (`fm1`, `fm2`) and together (`fm3`).  Finally fit the model with different `Asym` parameters (`fm4`).

```
# get starting values
fo <- Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets, A, lrc, c0)
fm1 <- nls(fo, df2, subset = Site == "ALT01")
fm2 <- nls(fo, df2, subset = Site == "ALT03")
fm3 <- nls(fo, df2)
st <- c(A1 = coef(fm1)[["A"]], A2 = coef(fm2)[["A"]], coef(fm3)[c("lrc", "c0")])

# fit    
fo4 <- Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets, A1*(Site=="ALT01")+A2*(Site=="ALT03"), lrc, c0)
fm4 <- nls(fo4, data = df2,  start = st)

plot(Cumulative.spp ~ Nets, df2, col = Site)
points(fitted(fm4) ~ Nets, df2, col = "red", pch = 20)
```

[image: screenshot]

**2) plinear** Actually `Asym` is special since the model is linear in it and we can use this to simplify the above as we don't need starting values for the linear parameters if we switch to `algorithm="plinear"`.  This eliminates the need to run `fm1` and `fm2`.  We only need `fm3` to generate starting values.  Note that `"plinear"` requires that the RHS of the formula be a matrix with each column multiplying the coefficient of one linear parameter.  Here we have two linear parameters (the `Asym` for each `Site`) so it is a two-column matrix.

```
# get starting values
fo <- Cumulative.spp ~ SSasympOff(Nets, A, lrc, c0)
fm3 <- nls(fo, df2)    
st5 <- coef(fm3)[c("lrc", "c0")]

# fit
mm <- with(df2, cbind(Site=="ALT01", Site=="ALT03"))
fo5 <- Cumulative.spp ~  mm * SSasympOff(Nets,1,lrc,c0)
fm5 <- nls(fo5, data = df2,  start = st5, algorithm = "plinear")
```

**2a)** `mm` could alternately be written like this which has the advantage that it extends to more sites:

```
mm <- model.matrix(~ Site - 1, transform(df2, Site = droplevels(Site)))
```

**2b)** If all levels of the `Site` factor are represented in the data then we could simplify even further as `droplevels(Site)` (which drops the unused levels) could then be simply `Site` allowing us to write:

```
mm <- model.matrix(~ Site - 1, df2)
```

**Update:** Some fixes and improvements.

Comment: it worked great, thanks. if is not too much problem, could you erase the first part, I feel that with the `mm <- model.matrix(~ Site - 1, transform(df2, Site = droplevels(Site)))
fo5 <- Cumulative.spp ~ mm * SSasympOff(Nets, 1, lrc, c0)`, together with then`fm5 <- nls(fo5, data = df2,  start = st5, algorithm = "plinear")` will do it, hte first part might confuse people, thanks

Comment: I have added headings.